# symfony4 swiftmailer non-existent class or interface: "Swift_Mailer"

Tags: symfony, email, swiftmailer, symfony4

after having installed swiftmailer with composer on symfony4

`composer require mailer`

I've written a small function to test it

```
/**
 * @Route("/testmail", name="testmail")
 */
public function mailAction(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom('test@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('test@gmail.com')
        ->setBody('Test content')
    ;

    $mailer->send($message);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('rotta');
}
```

the mailer URL is configured accordingly in .env

```
MAILER_URL=gmail://myaccount:mypassword@localhost
```

but by calling my function I get the following error message

```
Cannot determine controller argument for "App\Controller\RottaController::mailAction()": the $mailer argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or interface: "Swift_Mailer".
```

when I execute

```
./bin/console debug:config framework
```

Swiftmailer do not appear, does the service registration fail? What shall I check?

thanks
Sébastien

Comment: after a rm -rf on vendor and a composer install the bug was gone